# install gitlab on Windows with Docker

Tags: windows, docker, gitlab

I searched a lot and found that `GitLab Community Edition` is not installed on `Windows` so now I want to install it with the help of Docker. I do not know that is it possible and how I can do it ?

Comment: Install Docker for Windows, then follow [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55385018/530545). It avoids the "volumes problem" and supports backup and restore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run gitlab-ce on windows using Docker. First, make sure docker is installed on Windows, otherwise [install it](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/).

A detailed documentation for how to run gitlab using Docker is found under [GitLab Docker images](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/) including how to access the web interface.

Comment: I had to mark this down because the documentation is meant for a Linux Docker inside of Windows, which means the instructions themselves for Gitlabs require knowledge of Linux.

Answer (score 9):

1. You need to install Docker for Windows.
2. Share drive for Docker (in Docker's settings > shared drives). For example, drive E:

   [image: settings]

3. Then, you need to create 3 directories on drive E: (`e:\gitlab\config`, `e:\gitlab\logs`, `e:\gitlab\data`)
4. From the Command Prompt, run:

   ```
   docker run --detach --hostname gitlab.yourdomain.ru 
   --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 --name gitlab 
   --restart always --volume e:\gitlab\config:/etc/gitlab 
   --volume e:\gitlab\logs:/var/log/gitlab 
   --volume e:\gitlab\data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
   ```

That's it! You have now successfully run GitLab image.

Comment: Unable to use the gitlab on Win, when mounting local disk (as in your example) - had an error: `Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Failed asserting that ownership of "/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh" was git:git`

Comment: This means that you have .ssh folder with wrong access rights. Try to delete .ssh folder in e:\gitlab\data.

Comment: the problem is with `/var/opt/gitlab` folder only. You can mount it, but you will not be able to start gitlab docker instance normally. As of the moment of writing there is no easy fix for that for docker for windows. Here is a thread on official forums: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/2280

Comment: @Alex, I solved it by changing `/var/opt/gitlab` to `/var/opt`

Comment: Actually the mounted folder is empty with my suggested solution, but at least docker runs without crashing

Comment: @alex The link for the issue on official forums has changed to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/2280

Answer (score 3):

You can check gitlab documantation from [Expose GitLab on different ports](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html) section.

Before starting the installation create 3 folder which names "**config**","**data**","**logs**" in a "**gitlab**" folder. And run your [gitlab-ce](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/) image with docker run command.Gitlab should be running firstly.

> Note that I will use 8082 port for gitlab server.You can change it with any port number.

1-open cmd and show your IP address.You need to look for the IPv4 Address in your network adapter :

`ipconfig`

[image]

2-Run your docker-ce image with this command :

`docker run --detach --hostname YOUR-IP-ADRESS --publish 8082:8082 --publish 2282:22 --name gitlab --restart always --volume D:\DevOps\Gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab --volume D:\DevOps\Gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume D:\DevOps\Gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest`

[image]
3-In docker terminal(in docker gui application press to "cli" buton) go here :

`cd etc/gitlab`

`nano gitlab.rb`

4-Go to end of file at gitlab.rb and write these lines :

`external_url "http://your-ip-address:8082"`

`gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2282`

5-After save and close to gitlab.rb file enter this code for reconfiguration:

`gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

6-Remove your docker container and run with this command again:

`docker run --detach --hostname YOUR-IP-ADRESS --publish 8082:8082 --publish 2282:22 --name gitlab --restart always --volume D:\DevOps\Gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab --volume D:\DevOps\Gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume D:\DevOps\Gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest`

Comment: I used 127.0.0.1 as the IP address which basically means the local machine..
Also, after trying to hit http://127.0.0.1:8082, I was prompted to provide an admin password which always failed.
To get past this, I could go to the CLI a second time and run this command to set the root password:
    # gitlab-rake "gitlab:password:reset[root]"
Then enter the new password twice.
Now when you hit the http://127.0.0.1:8082, you can login as 'root' and the new password.

Comment: You should not use the default localhost IP on the Docker CLI. Because Docker creates a virtual system. This virtual system has a different IP number. When you hit localhost or 127.0.0.1 on the docker you mean different IP from your real system IP.So it could be a problem for installation. Please start from 1st step and reinstall it.

Comment: Hello @ÖmürAlçin. I'm trying to understand which IP I must use from ipconfig. I'd like to run GitLab Docker on my machine to test it, but which hostname should I use? Thank you.

Comment: Hii @Davide3i, you need to find the internal IP address. If you are using wifi, search it in the "Wireless LAN Address" else go to the "Ethernet adapter." then find "IPv4 Address" is your internal IP

Comment: So, considering those addresses are not static, I would have to change the hostname each time I restart my host? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here, there is a issue related with volumes when installing in Docker for Windows

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/2280

Answer (score 1):

Use the following docker-compose file:

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:13.7.1-ce'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'localhost'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
#KO      gitlab_rails['initial_root_password'] = 'adminadmin'
      gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2222
      external_url 'http://localhost'
  ports:
    - '8185:80'
    - '1443:443'
    - '2222:22'
  volumes:
    - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
#important here: do not mount /var/opt/gitlab but /var/opt as stated here: 
# https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/2280
    - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt'
```

Do (cygwin) `docker ps | grep gitlab` until status (healthy) is shown, then open a browser at http://localhost:8185

If you are not asked the first time to change root password,
set it like this (cygwin):

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep gitlab | awk '{print $1}') bash

root@dev:/# gitlab-rails console -e production
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Ruby:         ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
 GitLab:       13.12.5 (f37a805b0b4) FOSS
 GitLab Shell: 13.18.0
 PostgreSQL:   12.6
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Loading production environment (Rails 6.0.3.6)
irb(main):001:0> user = User.where(id: 1).first                                                                                                                                         => #<User id:1 @root>
irb(main):002:0> user.password = 'adminadmin'                                                                                                                                           => "adminadmin"
irb(main):003:0> user.password_confirmation = 'adminadmin'                                                                                                                              => "adminadmin"
irb(main):004:0> user.save                                                                                                                                                              Enqueued ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: d5dce701-2a79-4bed-b0a4-2abb877c2081) to Sidekiq(mailers) with arguments: "DeviseMailer", "password_change", "deliver_now", {:args=>[#<GlobalID:0x00007f621582b210 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://gitlab/User/1>>]}
=> true
irb(main):005:0> exit
```

Then login, create a user, give him a first password, login with it update password, create a project, and use project's git url rather than http since the use of a port seems to generate some trouble with the http url. Generating a public private/key and registering the public on in gitlab might be required