# run GitLab with docker image in windows 10 on localhost

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed a docker image "gitlab/gitlab-ce" on windows 10 and I try to run with following command.

```
docker run --detach --hostname https://localhost/ --publish 40443:80 --name GitLab --restart always --volume d:\gitlab\config:/etc/gitlab --volume d:\gitlab\logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume d:\gitlab\data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

but when it doesn't accessible in browser.
"This site can’t be reached.
localhost unexpectedly closed the connection."

I don't known what is wrong here in GitLab document the host name is "gitlab.example.com" and I don't known what is domain refer to.

Answer (score 2):

You should use your own ip instead of "localhost" word.Because localhost IP is different for the docker.So you should check your ip address with `ipconfig` cmd command.And set the docker run command with your ip address.

I have write step by step at this comment : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66357935/11040700

Comment: Thanks a lot. We switch to azure devops that is better for win server .

Answer (score 0):

Your docker container is exposed on :40443 port

Ref.: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

P.S. hostname should be without https://

Comment: docker run --detach --hostname localhost --publish 40443:80 --name gitlab --restart always --volume d:\gitlab\config:/etc/gitlab --volume d:\gitlab\logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume d:\gitlab\data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest